# $.totalStorage is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

данный плагин - totalStorage - подключен в начале загружаемой страницы. Однако при его использовании на странице, в консоли  Uncaught TypeError: $.totalStorage is not a function
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где порыть. Спасибо

Подключение: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «данный плагин» — это какой?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего у Вас не правильный порядок подключаемых библиотек. Сначала должна прогружаться библиотека `jQuery`, а после плагин. Или у Вас не подключен `jQuery`. Если порядок верный убедитесь что у Вас:

1. Библиотека jQuery прогружается корректно;
2. Библиотека jQuery - подключается только один раз;

Comment: загрузил последовательность подключения, JQuery прогружается корректно, подключена только 1 раз. Ошибка по-прежнему появляется

Comment: А если попробовать `$.totalStorage` заменить на `jQuery.totalStorage`. Либо там где вызываете обвернуть в `jQuery(function($){$.totalStorage })`

Comment: и так, и так - без изменений, ошибка та же

Comment: @proshka, а есть ли ошибки, кроме этой? Очистили ли кэш? Есть ли сайт в публичном доступе?

Comment: ошибок более нет. Все, что касается использования JQuery на данной странице, отрабатывает без ошибок, следовательно подключение JQuery корректно.

Comment: сайта на продакшене нет, только на локалке

Comment: Вы не одни https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=165208.